# Setting up autostart application in Xubuntu

Tags: autostart, startup-applications

I have a problem with a startup application.
I have a miner ([EWBF 0.3.4b](https://github.com/nanopool/ewbf-miner/releases/tag/v0.3.4b)) located in /home/kriszcash/Desktop/0.3.4b/. When I start the computer, I need to open a terminal and run

```
cd /home/kriszcash/Desktop/0.3.4b/
./miner
```

And after that miner start I look here and in the internet, I tried it with a desktop file, session and startup and edit `local.d` and other, but i can't bring it to start automatically.
My idea is when I start linux, the terminal should open and some script should write `cd /home/kriszcash/Desktop/0.3.4b/` and `./miner`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

To add an application to your autostart programs just copy its `.desktop` file to `~/.config/autostart/`. Make sure the `Exec` line of the file says

```
Exec=/home/kriszcash/Desktop/0.3.4b/miner
```

Comment: Hello i try but don't run. When i restart no runnig! Why ?! Please helpme

Comment: Please add the content of your `.desktop` file to your question using a code block (`{}` button).